# How can I send a Ping frame via WebSocket ? My Playframework version is 1.2.7

Tags: playframework, websocket

I just find the Ping frame some source code in \framework\src\play\server\PlayHandler.java. 
And it will handle the ping frame with follow codes.
But I cannot find what time the ping frame will auto send ? Or any other api to send a ping frame by myself?

```
private void websocketFrameReceived(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WebSocketFrame webSocketFrame) {
        Http.Inbound inbound = channels.get(ctx);
        // Check for closing frame
        if (webSocketFrame instanceof CloseWebSocketFrame) {
            this.handshaker.close(ctx.getChannel(), (CloseWebSocketFrame) webSocketFrame);
        } else if (webSocketFrame instanceof PingWebSocketFrame) {
            ctx.getChannel().write(new PongWebSocketFrame(webSocketFrame.getBinaryData()));
        } else if (webSocketFrame instanceof BinaryWebSocketFrame) {
            inbound._received(new Http.WebSocketFrame(webSocketFrame.getBinaryData().array()));
        } else if (webSocketFrame instanceof TextWebSocketFrame) {
            inbound._received(new Http.WebSocketFrame(((TextWebSocketFrame)webSocketFrame).getText()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I personally send ping request using play jobs. After reading http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.2 I did this:
byte pingByte = 9;
byte[] pingData = {9}; 
outbound.send(pingByte, pingData);